# Linking to a Lotus Notes Document from MediaWiki

Tags: lotus-notes, mediawiki

I've recently joined a company where groups maintain a lot of data in a lot of systems.  The group that I'm in uses MediaWiki and there are some Lotus Notes documents that I want to link to there.  The notes "URL" is in the following format - Notes://PATH_TO_DOCUMENT/DOCUMENT_NUMBER

Anybody know how I can have a hyperlink to this document?  I'm ok with sticking with IE as this wiki has a lot of file links formatted that work best in IE.

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted your question correctly.  I interpreted it that you don't want people to have to have Lotus Notes installed and in order to access the documents that you want to link.  If you're actually okay with that, and are really just asking how to find the PATH_TO_DOCUMENT/DOCUMENT_NUMBER information, let me know by replying here, and I will update my answer.

Comment: All users will have Lotus Notes installed.  I know how to find the Notes://PATH_TO_DOCUMENT/DOCUMENT_NUMBER but I'm trying to figure out how to use that path as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols) from [MediaWiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org), you may need to change the configuration of your wiki instance to allow the unrecognized protocol **notes://**.

From the article:

The default value in MediaWiki 1.20.0 is

```
$wgUrlProtocols = array(
    'http://',
    'https://',
    'ftp://',
    'irc://',
    'ircs://',  // @bug 28503
    'gopher://',
    'telnet://', // Well if we're going to support the above.. -ævar
    'nntp://', // @bug 3808 RFC 1738
    'worldwind://',
    'mailto:',
    'news:',
    'svn://',
    'git://',
    'mms://',
    '//', // for protocol-relative URLs
);
```

You will need to add your protocol to the end (something like this):

```
$wgUrlProtocols = array(
    'http://',
    'https://',
    'ftp://',
    'irc://',
    'ircs://',  // @bug 28503
    'gopher://',
    'telnet://', // Well if we're going to support the above.. -ævar
    'nntp://', // @bug 3808 RFC 1738
    'worldwind://',
    'mailto:',
    'news:',
    'svn://',
    'git://',
    'mms://',
    'notes://',
    '//', // for protocol-relative URLs
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  In the end, this was the solution that I went with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a link that opens the Lotus Notes documents so you can view them in IE, then you will have to consult with the administrators of your Lotus Notes and Domino system.  Ask them whether your Lotus Domino servers are running the Domino HTTP task.  If the server are running HTTP, then it could be possible to use a regular "http://..." link to bring the documents up in a browser, however you would still need more information.  I.e., the hostname or IP address of the server, your username and password for HTTP access, and the path to the database.  You should discuss the first two with your Lotus Domino administrators.  The last one you can by opening the database in your Notes client and bringing up the Database Properties dialog -- that's on the File menu, either under 'Application' or 'Database' depending on how old your version of Lotus Notes is.  It will be a file path ending in ".nsf".  With this info, you can construct a URL to try in your browser:

```
http://domino-server-host-or-ip/path-ending-in-dot-nsf
```

After the login and password prompt, you should see the web presentation of your Lotus Notes database.  This may turn out to be pretty ugly.  It may require loading Java applets to run in your browser.  This all depends on how the database was built, and how old the versions of Lotus Notes and Domino are. But if everything has been set up reasonably, you should be able to find your documents, capture the URLs in your browser, and use them as links within MediaWiki.  Of course, only people who have login and passwords set up on the Domino server will be able to use those links.

Comment: Cool.  I'll look into this.  Fortunately the Notes guys sit right next to me.